# How to cancel the reference by locate?

Tags: vim, system-preferences, locate

My os info:

```
uname -a
Linux mydebian 4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.171-2 (2021-01-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There is no `/usr/share/vim` in the os,it is my first time(never install before) to install vim with command:

```
sudo apt install vim
```

Now enter into vim ,type `scriptnames` in ex mode ,i get info:

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vim81/defaults.vim
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim81/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/gzip.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/logiPat.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/manpager.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/matchparen.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/spellfile.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tohtml.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

`vim` is installed entirely.
To remove the vim and updatedb and remove directory `/usr/share/vim` manually.

```
sudo apt remove vim
sudo updatedb
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/vim
#or
sudo apt remove vim
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/vim
sudo updatedb
#the order is un-related,i have maken the experiment.
```

Now install vim the same way as first time to do:

```
sudo apt install vim
```

Enter into vim and type `:scriptnames` in ex mode,i get nothing shown.

```
ls  /usr/share/vim 
ls: cannot access '/usr/share/vim': No such file or directory
```

`vim` is installed partly.
As `duthils` point out in the webpage
[fix the issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1625085/why-installed-part-of-vim-instead-of-entire-diectories%60%20,%60sudo%20apt%20install%20--reinstall%20vim-runtime)
`apt install --reinstall vim-runtime` can fix the issue.
Yes!I have verified that for the second time installation (after to remove the vim and updatedb and remove directory `/usr/share/vim` manually)

```
sudo apt install vim
sudo apt install --reinstall vim-runtime
```

Or

```
sudo apt install vim-runtime vim
```

In the explanation:It seems that your directory `/usr/share/vim` was manually deleted (it is "not found" but still referenced by your original locate),it is true in my case,why `updatedb` can't cancel the reference by `locate`?How to cancel the reference properly by `locate`?
I want a pure functional way,same input same output,it is unacceptable to install same package `vim` with two different commands.

Comment: How is this post different from your [other post](https://superuser.com/questions/1625085/why-installed-part-of-vim-instead-of-entire-diectories)?

Comment: Why updatedb can't cancel the reference by locate?How to cancel the reference properly by locate?

Comment: `duthils` help me to install `vim` ,but i want a way to fix the package management system.

Comment: Why `sudo updatedb` can't restore my os into previous status?

Answer (score 0):

To regenerate the database of `locate`, you could try to rename the current database
and call again `updatedb`.

To find the database, run `man updatedb`. This information can be found under "Files".
Mine says: `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`.

If this works, you may delete the renamed file.

Comment: The directory is /var/cache/locate/locatedb  in my debian,it is no use to remove and regenerate and then install vim second time only with such command as `sudo apt install vim`.

Comment: You should regenerate the database after you have installed everything. This will take some time.